# Rewriterule in Slim Framework getting Error 500

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, slim

I have this problem, I'm running locally an application (PHP 5.3.5) and it works, but when I put it online it doesn't (I have PHP 5.3.6).

- http://domain.com/ //works
- http://domain.com/route //doesn't work Error 500
- http://domain.com/index.php/route //works

This is my '.htaccess'

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

As you can see I only added this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
I also tried with the original .htaccess but didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the server error log, chances are that it will have information on the thing going wrong here, assuming it really is a bad mod_rewrite rule.

Comment: I also did that. The log don't give me more information besides of the petition and the 500 state. I'm really stuck here

Comment: How about: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: It didn't work @smottt. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try with Wordpress default .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And it works

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me! I know A lot of people are struggling with this. But i hope this works for you guys too. Good Luck
Also don't forget to add this in your virtual host file...

```
AllowOverride All
```

Rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Thats works but when you send paramters. it just goes to 404 error. Anyone know how to solve that issue.?

Comment: Hey, @user1093704, first at all, had you try the  `.htaccess` I posted? If that doesn't help, you should ask another question for your 404 error.